# ¿Como mostrar los detalles en una tabla en Spring boot?

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, spring, jstl

Saludos a la comunidad estoy implementando el detalle pero a la hora de agregar los datos como nombre del producto, la cantidad, peso bruto, Tara, Peso neto, Precio Compra ,Descuento.
No me agrega el Nombre del producto,cantidad,precio compra ,peso neto, descuento y el subtotal

dejo el codigo.

el modelo.
OrdenCompra

```
 @Entity
public class OrdenCompra implements Serializable{
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "idordencompra", updatable = false, nullable = false,unique=true)
    private Long idordencompra;
    
    @Column(name="numero",nullable=false,length=6)
    private String numero;
    
    @Column(name="serie",nullable=false,length=3)
    private String serie;
    
    @NotNull(message="No puede estar vacio")
    @Column(name="fecha_emision")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date fechaemision;
    
    @Column(name="observaciones",nullable=false,length=300)
    private String observaciones;
    

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE},orphanRemoval = true )
    @JoinColumn(name="idordencompra")
    private List<DetalleOrdenCompra> detalleordencompra=new ArrayList<DetalleOrdenCompra>();
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="idproveedor")
    private Proveedor proveedor;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="idtipopago")
    private TipoPago tipopago;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="idmoneda")
    private Moneda moneda;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="idalmacen")
    private Almacen almacen;

    @PrePersist
    public void prePersist() {
        
        fechaemision=new Date();
    }
    
    public Proveedor getProveedor() {
        return proveedor;
    }

    public void setProveedor(Proveedor proveedor) {
        this.proveedor = proveedor;
    }

    public Long getIdordencompra() {
        return idordencompra;
    }

    public void setIdordencompra(Long idordencompra) {
        this.idordencompra = idordencompra;
    }

    public String getNumero() {
        return numero;
    }

    public void setNumero(String numero) {
        this.numero = numero;
    }

    public String getSerie() {
        return serie;
    }

    public void setSerie(String serie) {
        this.serie = serie;
    }
    public Date getFechaemision() {
        return fechaemision;
    }

    public void setFechaemision(Date fechaemision) {
        this.fechaemision = fechaemision;
    }
    public String getObservaciones() {
        return observaciones;
    }

    public void setObservaciones(String observaciones) {
        this.observaciones = observaciones;
    }   
    public Double getTotal() {
        
        Double total=0.0;
        int size=detalleordencompra.size();
        
        for(int i=0; i< size;i++) {
            total +=((List<DetalleOrdenCompra>) detalleordencompra).get(i).calcularSubTotal();
        }
        return total;
    }
    public List<DetalleOrdenCompra> getDetalleordencompra() {
        return detalleordencompra;
    }
    public void setDetalleordencompra(List<DetalleOrdenCompra> detalleordencompra) {
        this.detalleordencompra = detalleordencompra;
    }
    public OrdenCompra() {
        this.detalleordencompra=new ArrayList<DetalleOrdenCompra>();
    }
    public OrdenCompra(String numero, String serie, @NotNull(message = "No puede estar vacio") Date fechaemision,
            String observaciones, List<DetalleOrdenCompra> detalleordencompra, Proveedor proveedor) {
        super();
        this.numero = numero;
        this.serie = serie;
        this.fechaemision = fechaemision;
        this.observaciones = observaciones;
        this.detalleordencompra = detalleordencompra;
        this.proveedor = proveedor;
    }


public DetalleOrdenCompra getDetalleOrdenCompraAt(Integer index) {
    DetalleOrdenCompra detalle=null;
    
    if(detalleordencompra.size()> index) {
        detalle=detalleordencompra.get(index);
    }
    
    return detalle;
}

public TipoPago getTipopago() {
    return tipopago;
}
public void setTipopago(TipoPago tipopago) {
    this.tipopago = tipopago;
}
public Moneda getMoneda() {
    return moneda;
}
public void setMoneda(Moneda moneda) {
    this.moneda = moneda;
}
public Almacen getAlmacen() {
    return almacen;
}
public void setAlmacen(Almacen almacen) {
    this.almacen = almacen;
}   
}
```

el detalle

```
@Entity
public class DetalleOrdenCompra implements Serializable{

    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "iddetalleordencompra", updatable = false, nullable = false,unique=true)
    private Long iddetalleordencompra;
    
    private Integer cantidad;
    

    @Column(name="pesobruto",precision=10,scale=2,columnDefinition="Decimal(10,2)")
    private Double pesobruto;
    
    @Column(name="tara",precision=10,scale=2,columnDefinition="Decimal(10,2)")
    private Double tara;
    
    @Column(name="pesoneto",precision=10,scale=2,columnDefinition="Decimal(10,2)")
    private Double pesoneto;
    
    @Column(name="descuento",precision=10,scale=2,columnDefinition="Decimal(10,2)")
    private Double descuento;
    
    @Column(name="subtotal",precision=10,scale=2,columnDefinition="Decimal(10,2)")
    private Double subtotal;
    
    @Column(name="preciocompra",precision=10,scale=2,columnDefinition="Decimal(10,2)")
    private Double preciocompra;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="idordencompra")   
    private OrdenCompra ordencompra;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="idproducto")
    private Producto producto;
    
    




    public Long getIddetalleordencompra() {
        return iddetalleordencompra;
    }

    public void setIddetalleordencompra(Long iddetalleordencompra) {
        this.iddetalleordencompra = iddetalleordencompra;
    }



    public Integer getCantidad() {
        return cantidad;
    }

    public void setCantidad(Integer cantidad) {
        this.cantidad = cantidad;
    }

    public Producto getProducto() {
        return producto;
    }

    public void setProducto(Producto producto) {
        this.producto = producto;
    }

    
    public OrdenCompra getOrdencompra() {
        return ordencompra;
    }

    public void setOrdencompra(OrdenCompra ordencompra) {
        this.ordencompra = ordencompra;
    }
    
    
    
    public Double calcularSubTotal() {
        return getPesoneto() * producto.getPreciocompra();
    }

    

    
    public DetalleOrdenCompra(Integer cantidad, Producto producto) {
    
        this.cantidad = cantidad;
        this.producto = producto;
    }

    public DetalleOrdenCompra() {
    
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public Double getPesobruto() {
        return pesobruto;
    }

    public void setPesobruto(Double pesobruto) {
        this.pesobruto = pesobruto;
    }

    public Double getTara() {
        return tara;
    }

    public void setTara(Double tara) {
        this.tara = tara;
    }

    public Double getPesoneto() {
        return pesoneto;
    }

    public void setPesoneto(Double pesoneto) {
        this.pesoneto = pesoneto;
    }

    public Double getDescuento() {
        return descuento;
    }

    public void setDescuento(Double descuento) {
        this.descuento = descuento;
    }

    public Double getSubtotal() {
        return getPesoneto() * producto.getPreciocompra();
    }

    public void setSubtotal(Double subtotal) {
        this.subtotal = subtotal;
    }

    public Double getPreciocompra() {
        return preciocompra;
    }

    public void setPreciocompra(Double preciocompra) {
        this.preciocompra = preciocompra;
    }

    public DetalleOrdenCompra(Long iddetalleordencompra, Integer cantidad, Double pesobruto, Double tara,
            Double pesoneto, Double descuento, Double subtotal, Double preciocompra, OrdenCompra ordencompra,
            Producto producto) {
    
        this.iddetalleordencompra = iddetalleordencompra;
        this.cantidad = cantidad;
        this.pesobruto = pesobruto;
        this.tara = tara;
        this.pesoneto = pesoneto;
        this.descuento = descuento;
        this.subtotal = subtotal;
        this.preciocompra = preciocompra;
        this.ordencompra = ordencompra;
        this.producto = producto;
    }
    
}
```

el repository

```
public interface OrdenCompraRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<OrdenCompra, Long> {

}
```

los servicios

```
public interface OrdenCompraService {


void agregarOrdenCompra(OrdenCompra ordencompra, Double descuento,Double subtotal,Double pesobruto,Double pesoneto,Double tara,Double preciocompra,Integer cantidad);

}
```

```
@Service
public class OrdenCompraServiceImpl implements OrdenCompraService {

private OrdenCompraRepository ordenCompraRepository;

    @Autowired
    public OrdenCompraServiceImpl(OrdenCompraRepository ordenCompraRepository) {
    
        this.ordenCompraRepository = ordenCompraRepository;
    }


    @Override
    public void agregarOrdenCompra(OrdenCompra ordencompra, Double descuento,Double subtotal,Double pesoneto,Double pesobruto,Double tara,Double preciocompra,Integer cantidad) {
        
          List<DetalleOrdenCompra> detalleOrden =new ArrayList<DetalleOrdenCompra>();         
          ordencompra.setDetalleordencompra(null);
          for(DetalleOrdenCompra det: detalleOrden) {  
          
          det.setIddetalleordencompra(ordencompra.getIdordencompra());
        
          det.setProducto(det.getProducto());
          det.setCantidad(cantidad);
          det.setPesobruto(pesobruto);
          det.setTara(tara);
          det.setPesoneto(pesoneto);
          det.setPreciocompra(preciocompra);
          det.setDescuento(det.getDescuento());
          det.setSubtotal(det.getSubtotal());
         
          
          detalleOrden.add(det);
          
          }
         
          ordencompra.setDetalleordencompra(detalleOrden);
        
         
        
    }


}
```

en el controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/ordencompra", params={"agregarordencompra"} , method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String agregarOrdenCompras(
            @ModelAttribute("ordencompras") OrdenCompra ordencompra,          
              @RequestParam(name="cantidad") Integer cantidad,            
              @RequestParam(name="descuento") Double descuento,           
              @RequestParam(name="pesobruto") Double pesobruto,           
              @RequestParam(name="tara") Double tara,             
              @RequestParam(name="pesoneto") Double pesoneto,             
              @RequestParam(name="preciocompra") Double preciocompra,             
              @RequestParam(name="subtotal" , required = false) Double subtotal,            
              Model model ) {
        
        
        
        model.addAttribute("subtotal", subtotal);
        ordenCompraService.agregarOrdenCompra(ordencompra,descuento,subtotal,pesobruto,pesoneto,tara,preciocompra,cantidad);
    
        return "redirect:/compras/ordencompra";
    }
```

en el JSTL

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<c:set var="path" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"></c:set>
    
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<%@include file="/template/header.jsp"%>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${path}/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<title>Orden de Compra</title>
</head>
<body>
    <br>
    
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="card card-outline-secondary">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form:form action="${path}/compras/ordencompra" method="post" >
                    
                            
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label  class="control-label col-md-2">Orden de Compra</label>
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="serie" name="serie" value="${serie}" autofocus />
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="numero" name="numero" value="${numero}" autofocus />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <br>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="proveedor" class="control-label col-md-2">Proveedor</label>

                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <select name="proveedor" id="proveedor" required>
                                            <option value="-1">Eliga Proveedor</option>
                                        <c:forEach items="${proveedores}" var="proveedor">
                                            <option value="${proveedor.idproveedor}">${proveedor.razonsocial.nombre}</option>
                                        </c:forEach>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <label for="proveedor" class="control-label col-md-2">Representante</label>

                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <select name="proveedor" id="proveedor" required>
                                    <option value="-1">Eliga Representante</option>
                                        <c:forEach items="${proveedores}" var="proveedor">
                                            <option value="${proveedor.idproveedor}">${proveedor.representante}</option>
                                        </c:forEach>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                

                                
                                    
                            </div>
                            <br>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                
                                


                                <label for="almacen" class="control-label col-md-1">Almacen</label>

                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <select name="almacen" id="almacen" required>
                                    <option value="-1">Eliga Almacen</option>
                                        <c:forEach items="${almacenes}" var="almacen">
                                            <option value="${almacen.idalmacen}">${almacen.nombre}</option>
                                        </c:forEach>
                                    </select>
                                </div>


                            </div>
                            <br>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                
                                <label for="moneda" class="control-label col-md-1">Moneda</label>

                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <select name="moneda" id="moneda" required >
                                        <option value="-1">Eliga Moneda</option>
                                        <c:forEach items="${monedas}" var="moneda">
                                            <option value="${moneda.idmoneda}">${moneda.descripcion}</option>
                                        </c:forEach>
                                    </select>
                                </div>

                                <label for="fechaemison" class="col-md-1 control-label">Fecha emision</label>
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="fechaemision"  />
                                </div>
                                

                            </div>
                            <br>
                            
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                
                                <label for="tpago" class="control-label col-md-1">Tipo pago:</label>

                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <select name="tipopago" id="tipopago"  required >
                                    <option value="-1">Eliga Tipo de Pago</option>
                                        <c:forEach items="${tipopagos}" var="tipopago">
                                            <option value="${tipopago.idtipopago}">${tipopago.descripcion}</option>
                                        </c:forEach>
                                    </select>
                                </div>  
                                <label for="observaciones" class="control-label col-md-2">Observaciones</label>
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="observaciones" name="observaciones"  autofocus />
                                </div>          
                                

                            </div>
                            
                        
                        <div class="myForm27">  
                        
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="proveedor" class="control-label col-md-2">Producto</label>
                                <label for="proveedor" class="control-label col-md-2">Cantidad</label>
                                <label for="proveedor" class="control-label col-md-2">Peso Bruto</label>
                                <label for="proveedor" class="control-label col-md-1">Tara</label>
                                <label for="proveedor" class="control-label col-md-2">Peso Neto</label>
                                <label for="proveedor" class="control-label col-md-1">Precio compra</label>
                                <label for="proveedor" class="control-label col-md-2">Descuento</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <select name="producto" id="producto" required>
                                                <option value="-1">Seleccione Producto</option>
                                        <c:forEach items="${productos}" var="producto">
                                            <option  data-preciocompra="${producto.preciocompra}"  value="${producto.idproducto}">${producto.nomproducto}</option>
                                        </c:forEach>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <input type="text" pattern="\d*" class="form-control" name="cantidad" id="cantidad" autofocus required/>
                                </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="pesobruto" id="pesobruto" onkeyup="restar();" autofocus required/>
                                </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-1">
                                    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="tara" id="tara" onkeyup="restar();" autofocus required/>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="pesoneto" id="pesoneto"  readonly autofocus />
                                </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-1">
                                    <input type="text" pattern="\d*" class="form-control" name="preciocompra" id="preciocompra" value="${producto.preciocompra}" readonly  required/>
                                </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="descuento"  name="descuento" value=0  readonly />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                    
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            
                                <div class="col-md-12 col-md-offset-2">
                                    <div class="card">
                                        <div class="card-body ">
                                            
                                            <button type="submit"  name="agregarordencompra" class="btn btn-success float-right " >Agregar</button>
                                           
                                        </div>
                                   
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    
                    
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="tabla2">
                            <thead>
                              <tr>
                                    <th>Producto</th>
                                    <th>Cantidad</th>
                                    <th>Precio Compra</th>
                                     <th>Peso Neto</th>
                                    <th>Descuento</th>
                                    <th>Total</th>
                                    <th>Opciones</th>
                              </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                             
                            </tbody>
                        
                        </table>
                        </div>
                    
                        <div class="form-group row justify-content-end">
                            <label for="subtotal" class="control-label col-md-2">SubTotal</label>
                            <label for="descuento" class="control-label col-md-2">Descuento</label>
                            
                            <label for="descuento" class="control-label col-md-2">I.G.V</label>
                            <label for="descuento" class="control-label col-md-2">Total</label>
                        </div>
                         <div class="form-group row justify-content-end">
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <input type="number" class="form-control"  readonly id="subtotal"  name="subtotal" autofocus />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <input type="number" class="form-control" readonly id="descuento1" autofocus />
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <input type="number" class="form-control" readonly id="impuesto" autofocus />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <input type="number" class="form-control" readonly id="total" autofocus />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                      </form:form>
        
        
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            
                                <div class="col-md-12 col-md-offset-2">
                                    <div class="card">
                                        <div class="card-body ">
                                            
                                            <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-success float-right " >Guardar</button>
                                           
                                        </div>
                                   
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
        
          </div>
        
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    
    
   
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="${path}/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="${path}/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="${path}/js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="${path}/js/main.js"></script>
 <script>

  
    $('#producto').on('change', function() {
   
      let precioCompra = $('#producto option:selected').attr('data-preciocompra');
     
      $('#preciocompra').val(precioCompra);
    });
    

    </script>
</html>
```

en el script

```
function restar()
{
    let precio1 = document.getElementById("pesobruto");
    let precio2 = document.getElementById("tara");
    let precio3 = document.getElementById("pesoneto");
    
    precio2.addEventListener("change", () => {
        precio3.value = parseFloat(precio1.value) - parseFloat(precio2.value);

    })
}

function carcularsubtotal()
{
    let pesoneto = document.getElementById("pesoneto");
    let preciocompra = document.getElementById("preciocompra");
    let subtotal = document.getElementById("subtotal");
    
    subtotal.addEventListener("change", () => {
        subtotal.value = parseFloat(pesoneto.value) * parseFloat(preciocompra.value);

    })
}


function agregarOrdenCompra(){
    
    
     let cantidad = document.getElementById('cantidad').value;
   
     let pesoneto = document.getElementById('pesoneto').value;
     let descuento = document.getElementById('descuento').value;
     let producto = document.getElementById('producto').options[document.getElementById('producto').selectedIndex].text;    
     let preciocompra = parseFloat(document.getElementById("preciocompra").value);
     // document.getElementById("preciocompra").value = producto;
     
     
     
     let subtotal=parseFloat((preciocompra*pesoneto)-descuento).toFixed(2);
        
     
    let impuesto=Number.parseFloat(subtotal*0.19).toFixed(2);
        impuesto= document.getElementById('impuesto').value;
    let total=Number.parseFloat(subtotal).toFixed(2)+Number.parseFloat(impuesto).toFixed(2);
        total= document.getElementById('total').value;
    
   // let table = document.getElementsByTagName('tabla2')[0];
      
        let table = document.getElementById('tabla2');
      let newRow = table.insertRow(table.rows.length);
      
    
      let cel1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
      let cel2 = newRow.insertCell(1);
      let cel3 = newRow.insertCell(2);
      let cel4 = newRow.insertCell(3);
      let cel5 = newRow.insertCell(4);
      let cel6 = newRow.insertCell(5);   
      let cel7= newRow.insertCell(6);
       
      
      cel1.innerHTML = producto;
      cel2.innerHTML = cantidad;
      cel3.innerHTML = preciocompra;
      cel4.innerHTML = pesoneto;
      cel5.innerHTML = descuento;
      cel6.innerHTML = subtotal;   
      
     
 
      
      cel7.innerHTML = "<input type='button' value='Eliminar' onclick='deleteRow(this)'><input type='button' value='Actualizar'>";  
       
   
      
      calcularSubtotal();
      //deleteRow(tabla2);
      
    

    
}

$(document).on('change', '#producto', function(event) {
    $('#productoSelecionado').val($("#producto option:selected").text());
});

document.getElementById('producto').onchange = function() {
    var mOption = this.options[this.selectedIndex];
      /* Referencia a los atributos data de la opción seleccionada */
      var mData = mOption.dataset;
      var elId = document.getElementById('idproducto');
      var elPreciocompra = document.getElementById('preciocompra');
      
      elId.value = this.value;
      
      elPreciocompra.value = mOption.text; /*Se usará el valor que se muestra*/
}

function deleteRow(r)
{
var i=r.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
document.getElementById('tabla2').deleteRow(i);
calcularSubtotal();
}

 function calcularSubtotal(){
     
     var table = document.getElementById('tabla2');
        let subtotal = 0
        for(let i = 1; i<table.rows.length; i++){
            subtotal+=Number(table.rows[i].cells[5].innerText)
        }
        const totalInput = document.getElementById('subtotal')
        totalInput.value=subtotal
     
 }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en el Log me sale

Resolved

```
[org.springframework.web.bind.UnsatisfiedServletRequestParameterException: Parameter conditions "agregarOrdenCompra" not met for actual request parameters: serie={1}, numero={1}, proveedor={-1, -1}, almacen={-1}, moneda={-1}, tipopago={-1}, observaciones={}, producto={1}, cantidad={1234}, pesobruto={1234}, tara={123}, pesoneto={1111}, preciocompra={7.6}, descuento={0}, subtotal={8443.6}]
```

y despues me sale pagina no encontrada

alguien me puede ayudar en la comunidad o darme una idea muchas gracias

Comment: Cuando llene datos en el repository y los servicios y en el controlador no me deja agregar los campos me redirecciona y me sale vacío la tabla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya lo resolvi

$(document).ready(function () {
$("#btnAddRow").click(function () {

```
    let producto = document.getElementById('producto').options[document.getElementById('producto').selectedIndex].text;  
    var cantidad = $("#cantidad").val();
    let preciocompra = parseFloat(document.getElementById("preciocompra").value);
    let pesoneto = document.getElementById('pesoneto').value;
    let descuento = document.getElementById('descuento').value;
    let subtotal=parseFloat((preciocompra*pesoneto)-descuento).toFixed(2);
  
    var tr;
    tr = $('<tr/>');
    tr.append("<td>" + producto + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + cantidad + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + preciocompra + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + pesoneto + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + descuento + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + subtotal + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" +  "<input type='button' value='Eliminar' onclick='deleteRow(this)'><input type='button' value='Actualizar'>" + "</td>");
    
    
    
   
    $('#cargarDetalle').append(tr);
    calcularSubtotal();

});
```

});

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]